# Bleed Size for Exhibitor Stand In Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, page-layout, bleed

I need to make design for a company for the panels which we see in exhibitions.

But before starting it I would like to know how much bleed size should I leave for printing for such a big design. Artwork Sizes are as below :-

1. W - 1459mm  H - 394mm
2. W - 1954mm H - 394mm
3. W - 469mm H - 2354mm
4. W - 964mm H - 2354mm
5. W - 469mm H - 1424mm
6. W - 964mm H - 2354mm
7. W - 964mm H - 2354mm

Comment: If you're speaking of trade booth, the best is to get a template from the site of the printer. Some parts of these kind of banners need to be folded and require a few inches of "bleed", and other parts are simply cut. That's why the best is to refer to the printer's requirements that are usually available online. Most of the time they provide templates with the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As always, ask your printer first, but for some background:

Unless your printer is printing direct to media, it's highly likely that the prints are going to be mounted to some kind of substrate. That requires additional bleed, as the print can shift about slightly as it's being mounted down; the larger the print, the more it may shift. For panels that size I'd say 15-20mm bleed would probably be fine (you can never really have *too* much bleed).

If you're having a wrapped edge, don't forget to add the equivalent thickness of the material to your bleed; so if it's being mounted on 5mm foamex with a wrapped edge, you'd want 25mm bleed (20mm + 5mm). People forget this all the time. I've seen my fair share of artwork intended to wrap around 25mm substrates but they've only given me 3mm of bleed to work with.

Also, unless your printer asks you to, don't include crop marks. If you do get asked to include them, be sure to offset them so they're sitting just outside the bleed, not it, otherwise they may show up in your finished print.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on your printing solution.

I strongly advise you to ask your printing partner about this information.

If you don't have this chance, and if your design is not going to wrap a material like foamex, 15mm should cover it.